# Why does fftw3 inverse fourier transform's produces output vector of type double?

Tags: fft, fftw

I want to take inverse fourier transform of a signal. I use this

fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d

however, the output vector is required to be double. The question is isn't that the IFFT of a signal gives complex number result?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) allows for the time-domain input to be a complex valued signal and produces a frequency-domain result which is in general also complex valued. Correspondingly the inverse transform of that complex-valued frequency-domain result would produce the same (or at least within the available implementation's numerical precision) original time-domain signal. The result of the inverse transform *could* thus be complex.

Just the same, if we restrict time-domain inputs of the forward transform to real-valued signals then we would similarly expect the inverse transform of the corresponding frequency-domain spectrum to give us back the same original real-valued signal.

Note that the forward transform of those real-valued signal produces a frequency domain result that exhibits Hermitian symmetry (and conversely, if a frequency domain signal has Hermitian symmetry it must be the transform of a real valued signal). [`fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d`](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html) then computes the inverse transform (which is real-valued and stored in `double`) under the *assumption* that the frequency domain spectrum indeed has Hermitian symmetry.